# Python Identation error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I just cant figure out what is wrong with this code..It is showing error: "unindent doesnt match any outer indentation level
I have checked it using python -m tabnanny paint.py...It is showing something like this: "Identation error: unident does not match any outer level((tokensize>,line26>" but I just can't understand what it what to say..Please help me.
    #paint.py
    import sys,pygame
    import os
    from pygame.locals import *

```
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600))
screen.fill((255,255,255))
brush = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('C:\Python27','brush.png'))
brush = pygame.transform.scale(brush,(128,128))

pygame.display.update()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

z = 0

while 1:
    clock.tick(60)
x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
    sys.exit()
    elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    z=1
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
    z=0

    if z==1:
    screen.blit(brush,(x-64,y-64))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Did you try indenting like the tutorial shows you?

Comment: Yeah...It shows the same error

Comment: If the error doesn't go away then you still haven't done it as the tutorial shows.

Comment: Check that the indentation above matches what you have in your file, note that the first few lines aren't appearing as part of the code block above. If this is really what you have, there are at least 6 indentation errors.

Comment: i did it but still Let me try once again...I am trying to solve it from last half an hour but it shows the same error either with line elif event.type==MOUSEBUTTONUP or with elif event.type==MOUSEBUTTONDOWN...

Comment: Your if's and elif's should have the same indentation level, for a single if/elif/elif... chain.  The things they are supposed to executed need to be indented.  Are you using a development environment which can show you line numbers? Then you can follow the error you're given to the line number it refers to.

Comment: Yeah...I am using development environment which shows line numbers..And here line 26 refers to elif event.type==MOUSEBUTTONUP:..

Comment: Wohaa...I am done with it...Thank You So much all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several places where you are missing an indentation:

```
...
if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
sys.exit() # <-- missing indentation
elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
z=1 # <-- missing indentation
    elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
z=0 # <-- missing indentation
....
```

Note that the block to be executed under an `if` clause must be indented. Also I recommend you use a text editor which can show you white chars - it would be very difficult to catch these errors otherwise.

Comment: Ok..I will keep this in a mind..Can you please tell me the name/names of text editors which shows a white characters?

Comment: There is really an overwhelming selection of text editors, and I would guess that any modern editors has this feature. Wikipedia keeps [a very comprehensive comparison table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors). Currently I'm using the excellent free [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), which supports this feature.